# Creating a legal branch in git on a Mac precludes further pulls by Windows

Tags: windows, git, macos, branch

Suppose I create a branch with a legal name "prn" on a Mac

`git checkout prn`

I make some changes, commit and push. No problem. Someone else on my team who uses Windows pulls this same repository encounters the error:

cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/prn' prn .... -> origin/prn  (unable to update local ref)

Most posts on this error recommend

`git gc --prune=now`
`git remote prune origin`

However, this did not solve the error.

Comment: Note that this particular problem may eventually be fixed in some future version of Git by using "reftables". You'll still have all kinds of Windows-specific issues with naming anything `prn`, `con`, `aux`, and so on. macOS folks might be inclined to point and laugh, but they'll have issues with file names containing composing characters in Unicode. Only the Linux folks really have the right to point and laugh (at both Windows and macOS) here. 

Comment: @torek fair enough but I created this post to save some other person from having to search in vain for an answer to why a particular set of names might not work for a branch. I could not find a post that addressed this issue. As you say, Linux folks have the last laugh but I hoped this post would help other people. Since it is my first post, I can't tell if the down vote means the post is better a) taken down or b) posted elsewhere.

Comment: Alas, it's hard to say why anyone downvoted, unless the downvoter makes a comment too. (And I use both macOS and Unix-y systems myself :-) )

Comment: @torek Ah, well the point of having a broader thread on branch naming issues across operating systems seems even more useful than this one problem case. As you said, perhaps future releases of git will handle cross-operating system branch naming conflicts but until then, this post provides some future guidance on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a [list of reserved namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) that preclude git from creating the file "prn" at ./.git/refs/remotes/origin. To solve this, our team deleted the branch from the Mac computer:

```
git branch -d prn
git push -d origin prn
```

We then cleaned up references to this branch on both computers (Mac and Windows)

```
git gc --prune=now
git remote prune origin
```

The last line will throw an error on the Windows machine stating that branch doesn't exist, which is fine. We were able to pull on the Windows side no problem after this.